# How can I get a time value from HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of a time input element via JavaScript. When I try using `getElementById` the value that is displayed is:

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

If use `querySelectorAll`, the value is:

```
[NodeList]
```

I also tried to use the index, but nothing new happens.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="principal-grid">

    <title>Hour Control</title>

    <label class="description-values">In</label>
    <input id="data-in" type="time" class="values">

    <label class="description-values">Interval - Saída</label>
    <input id="data-interval-s" type="time" class="values">

    <label class="description-values">Interval - Volta</label>
    <input id="data-interval-v" type="time" class="values">

    <label class="description-values">Out</label>
    <input id="data-out" type="time" class="values">

    <input id="submit" type="submit" class="send" value="Send">

</div>
```

And this is the script:

```js
var dataIn = document.getElementById(['data-in']);
var dataInterval_out = document.getElementById(['data-interval-s']);
var dataInterval_in = document.getElementById(['data-interval-v']);
var dataOut = document.getElementById(['data-out']);

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function (e) {

    //test
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = dataIn + ' ' + dataInterval_out +
        ' ' + dataInterval_in + ' ' + dataOut;
}
```

Comment: Look into `document.getElementById('some id here').value`

Comment: `getElementById` does not take in an array.  It takes just a string, with the string being the id value. Edit: which you are doing for the `submit` and `test` one, so I'm not sure why your usages are different

Comment: @Taplar Although I did try the array syntax in Chrome console, and it does seem to return the correct element..probably fallbacks?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById  It expects a string.  If it works with an array, that is strange, but definitely not the intended usage.

Comment: Convert a NodeList with something like this ```Array.prototype.slice.call(document.childNodes)```    With ES6 you can use ```Array.from(myNodeList)``` so for example : wrap what ever function returns a NodeList in ```Array.from(thatFunction)```

Comment: Follow up, `["test"].toString()` => `test`, which is probably why it is not erroring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to note here:

First up, when you use: `var dataIn = document.getElementById(...)`

It's returning a reference to the html element identified by the Id string and storing it in the dataIn variable you created. If you want the *value* of that element, you need to use: `dataIn.value`.

Here's an updated version of your script that does what I think you want:

```
var dataIn = document.getElementById('data-in');
var dataInterval_out = document.getElementById('data-interval-s');
var dataInterval_in = document.getElementById('data-interval-v');
var dataOut = document.getElementById('data-out');

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function (e) {

    //test
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = dataIn.value + ' ' + dataInterval_out.value +
        ' ' + dataInterval_in.value + ' ' + dataOut.value;
}
```

The second thing is that `getElementById` takes a string value. You're wrapping it in `[]`'s, which is unnecessary.

One last note: `type="time"` is not supported on all browsers. (Safari doesn't support it for example). So you may want to look for an alternative method for collecting dates, if supporting macOS and iOS devices is important to you.

Comment: It was so simple!!
Thank you very much, I will continue studying!

Answer (score 0):

To get value of input using vanilla js, use .value property.

```
var dataIn = document.getElementById('data-in').value;
var dataInterval_out = document.getElementById('data-interval-s').value;
var dataInterval_in = document.getElementById('data-interval-v').value;
var dataOut = document.getElementById('data-out').value;
```

Also, getting element by id, use document.getElementById('elementId')